# Integration of Integer functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate $$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\lfloor2\sin x\rfloor\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I am getting confused over the number of intervals in which I should break this function. It's taking me a long time. Can you suggest some better way?

Comment: Try drawing graph if the function

Comment: $2\sin x$ attains very few integer values which can be calculated manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\left\lfloor 2\sin\pars{x}\right\rfloor
\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{\pi}\left\lfloor -2\sin\pars{x}\right\rfloor\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left\lfloor -2\cos\pars{x}\right\rfloor\dd x =
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left\lfloor -2\cos\pars{x}\right\rfloor\dd x
\\[5mm]
\stackrel{-2\cos\pars{x}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,&
\int_{-2}^{0}{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \over \root{1 - x^{2}/4}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\int_{-2}^{-1}{\dd x \over \root{1 - x^{2}/4}} -
\int_{-1}^{0}{\dd x \over \root{1 - x^{2}/4}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{-\,{5 \over 3}\,\pi} \approx -5.2360 \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: i really like this approach.

Comment: @CSquared Thanks. It’s the logical way !!!.

Comment: Thanks! It is a good approach.

Comment: @user272837 Thanks. It’s nice you found that it’s useful.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the points where:
$$2\sin(x)=1\to x=\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}$$
$$2\sin(x)=-1\to x=\frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{11\pi}{6}$$
and we know that:
$$-1\le\sin(x)\le1$$
so we can split our region into the following:
$$0\le x\le\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\le x\le\pi\to0\le2\sin(x)\le 1$$
$$\frac{\pi}{6}\le x\le\frac{5\pi}{6}\to1\le2\sin(x)\le2$$
$$\pi\le x\le\frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{11\pi}{6}\le x\le2\pi\to-1\le2\sin(x)\le0$$
$$\frac{7\pi}{6}\le x\le\frac{11\pi}{6}\to-2\le2\sin(x)\le-1$$
now splitting up the integral should be easy :)

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wl1jcccon7) is a nice plot of the graph. Also I realise now you only wanted the region $[\pi,2\pi]$ but I guess at least you can see it

Answer (score 0):

We need to find what integer values the function $f(x)=2\sin(x)$ takes on the interval $[\pi, 2\pi]$ and at what $x$ values they change.

Firstly, the function we have here is $2\pi$ periodic and on one half of the period, $[\pi, 2\pi]$, it will take on integer values of
$0,-1,$ and $-2$.

Secondly, notice that $f(\pi)=0$ and at $x=\frac{7\pi}{6}$, $f(\frac{7\pi}{6})=-1$ so we have our first limits of integration, namely, $\pi\to\frac{7\pi}{6}$.

The integrand then takes on the value $f(x)=-2$ from $x=\frac{7\pi}{6}$ to $x=\frac{11\pi}{6}$ because of the way the floor function works with negative numbers.

Finally, at from $x=\frac{11\pi}{6}$ to $x=2\pi$, the function takes on the value $-1$ and then goes to zero when $x=2\pi$.

Now we have all of our modified bounds of integration, so we conclude that $$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \lfloor2\sin(x)\rfloor\,dx=\int_{\pi}^{\frac{7\pi}{6}}-1\,dx+\int_{\frac{7\pi}{6}}^{\frac{11\pi}{6}}-2\,dx +\int_{\frac{11\pi}{6}}^{2\pi} -1\,dx=-\frac{5\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Is there any way to generalize it? It becomes cumbersome for large values of limits. And in some cases, if we are required to find the limits of integration of floor function, given it is equal to something, how do we go on about it?

Comment: @DatBoi I am not entirely sure. It depends a lot on your function.  There is a more elegant way in this particular case by making use of symmetry, but the main way to go about it is to find out what integer values the integrand takes on and where they change. Depending on the function, there may be patterns that make integration easier. I am also not entirely sure if there is a Lebesgue integral method that would be faster, but that is out of my scope of knowledge right now. As an example, take $\int_{0}^{10}\lfloor x\rfloor\,dx$ and see if you find a pattern.

Comment: I dont know them as well. Im gonna ask a new question. Join me there